# how can read a json nested in multiple levels

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "140964",
            "label": " 3688-RELT-PRD-LOGIN",
            "location": "St. Louis, MO",
            "startdate": "September 1, 2019 00:00:00",
            "enddate": "September 12, 2019 04:57:41",
            "statushistory": [
                {
                    "status": "DOWN",
                    "statustype": "Content error",
                    "starttime": "09-01-2019 00:00",
                    "endtime": "09-11-2019 23:57",
                    "duration": "950261"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "142285",
            "label": " 4316_Rebar Messaging_PROD",
            "location": "Chicago, IL",
            "startdate": "September 1, 2019 00:00:00",
            "enddate": "September 12, 2019 04:57:41",
            "statushistory": [
                {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "statustype": "OK",
                    "starttime": "09-01-2019 00:00",
                    "endtime": "09-11-2019 23:57",
                    "duration": "950261"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "153272",
            "label": "10002-Self Service SQL Failover",
            "location": "Miami, FL",
            "startdate": "September 1, 2019 00:00:00",
            "enddate": "September 12, 2019 04:57:41",
            "statushistory": [
                {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "statustype": "OK",
                    "starttime": "09-01-2019 00:00",
                    "endtime": "09-11-2019 23:57",
                    "duration": "950261"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "156764",
            "label": "10054-SMARTSUPPLY-PRD",
            "location": "Bangalore, India",
            "startdate": "September 1, 2019 00:00:00",
            "enddate": "September 12, 2019 04:57:41",
            "statushistory": [
                {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "statustype": "OK",
                    "starttime": "09-01-2019 00:00",
                    "endtime": "09-11-2019 23:57",
                    "duration": "950261"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "156764",
            "label": "10054-SMARTSUPPLY-PRD",
            "location": "Mumbai, India",
            "startdate": "September 1, 2019 00:00:00",
            "enddate": "September 12, 2019 04:57:41",
            "statushistory": [
                {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "statustype": "OK",
                    "starttime": "09-08-2019 10:35",
                    "endtime": "09-11-2019 23:57",
                    "duration": "307316"
                },
                {
                    "status": "DOWN",
                    "statustype": "Timeout warning",
                    "starttime": "09-08-2019 10:31",
                    "endtime": "09-08-2019 10:35",
                    "duration": "274"
                },
                {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "statustype": "OK",
                    "starttime": "09-01-2019 00:00",
                    "endtime": "09-08-2019 10:31",
                    "duration": "642670"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i have this above json file .
which holds multiple data set this is just an example with 5 .

i want to pull the status value from the above json .
We can usual do it by result['statushistory'][0]['status']

But it pulls only the 5 values . It is returning only the first value of 
the last statushistory .

How can i write a code which returns all the value of statushistory ?

And also if the statushistory doesnt have any status how can i mange that in the code ?(i.e return status only if statushistory has status present in it)

Comment: Hi, you should also post the code you are currently using to parse the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
statushistory_list = [result["statushistory"] for result in json_data["result"]]
status_list = [
    [item["status"] for item in statushistory if "status" in item]
    for statushistory in statushistory_list
]
```

this will get you:

```
[['DOWN'], ['UP'], ['UP'], ['UP'], ['UP', 'DOWN', 'UP']]
```

If it's not what you are looking for then, please show an example of the output you would like.